# How to get rid of Untitled DVD in Mac OS X's Finder navigation bar?

Tags: macos, dvd, finder, burning

I tried to burn a DVD in Mac OS X. It failed, and I was left with an Untitled DVD item in the navigation bar of Finder. It looks like this:

[image: Untitled DVD]

How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The corresponding folder must be deleted, and then can you just drag it out of the navigation bar? Normally it should make it disappear.

Comment: The folder was already gone, thanks for the tip on dragging it out, it worked.